# short short int in c?

Tags: c, char, boolean, int, short

I'm trying to squeeze as much out of my memory as possible.
I have a matrix of `4.9999995e13` ints but they only need to be true or false - basically I only need one bit of storage for each of these ints.

I understand that there are no single bit types in C (maybe someone can explain why, to me), and I also know that if a `short short int` existed it would be 1 byte, same as char. However all of the logical operations in C return ints (as well as a few other functions).

So my questions are:

- Is there some way of making a `short short int` exist?
- If I was to use `char` instead, would I have performance decrease because of all the casting to `int` that would have to be done?
- Is there another way that I'm missing?

Just in-case it's relevant, I am compiling with GCC for C99.

*EDIT* I've just seen on [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Primitive_data_types) that there is a `_Bool` type, is this actually standard?

Comment: Can you please clarify why they all have to be casted to `int`?

Comment: you could use bitfields ( http://codepad.org/HMz2f7OR ). Using `char` as a bitfield underlying type in C is implementation defined (which is why I didn't post it as an answer, because I don't feel like creating 32 bitfields for unsigned int now), but works for GCC.

Comment: Well I'm not sure if they do, I assumed that bitwise ORing two chars would require a cast since it will return an int, as per: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type#History

Comment: What do each of these bits represent?   How are you planning on accessing the value of bit[4264334543] for example, and what will you do with it?   I ask because there may be a more efficient way of storing data that depends on structure you haven't revealed.

Comment: @AShelly they represent an edge between two nodes in a graph. I need the values for very quick lookup to see if and edge exists or not.

Comment: Is your adjacency matrix sparse?

Comment: @Jacob, it's usually a little over 0.5, so an adjacency list would halving the memory use. But dividing that big number by 2 still gives you a very big number, but a lot slower lookup time.

Comment: I know this is unpopular on a C question but have you considered C++? It doesn’t have bit data types either (well actually it does but it’s a bit on the slim side) but unlike C it *allows you to define* bit fields with convenient syntax and semantics. Of course, C bit fields might actually be sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: Just curious, why do you need 6.5TB of booleans? I'm trying to guess a use case for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `_Bool` type is standard in the most recent version of C, but that's still not what you want, because a `_Bool` still takes up at least one byte (as does a `char`, by definition).

No, if you want that many boolean bits you need to pack them into a [bitfield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) or [bit array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array). There is no standard datatype for bitfields in C, so you're also going to have to write your own macros or functions for getting the bit at a particular offset. I also hope that you're going to run this on a 64-bit machine with plenty of RAM, otherwise you're going to run out of memory and fast.

Comment: Thanks, would this give me a big performance hit though? And yes, 32GB RAM available at the moment.

Comment: @Griffin, with data sizes as big as what you've got, the cost of moving things in and out of memory swamps the cost of execution. You don't have 5e13 bytes of memory, you only have ~3e10 on your machine, so anything you can possibly do to get the data set to fit into memory will be a win.

Comment: +1 actually, I'm creating and analysing very large graphs. The aim is to get 1e7 nodes (the order im asking about now) but really even the adjacency matrix for 1e6 would potentially take up 58GB or RAM. I can eventually port all of this over to OpenCL and run on the university's supercomputer, but it's still problematic. I've got a lot to think about. Thank you for opening my eyes somewhat! +1 to your answer too.

Comment: @Griffin, there are more efficient data structures for an adjacency matrix if that's what you're going for, and using them might reduce your memory footprint by a few orders of magnitude. You might try asking a separate question about that if that's what you're trying to build.

Answer (score 6):

You have about 50 terabits of data. Do you want to fit them all in RAM at once? It woulld be totally insane to use more than one bit of RAM in orrder to keep one bit of information, and even then your computer would have to be about the size of the largest supercomputer on this planet. Forget performance of bit-packing. You will have to worry about totally different things.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is a bitmap (or [bit array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array) as Wikipedia calls it).

And there is no such thing as a `short short int`, that's just a `char` which is the smallest integer storage class in C.

There might be some performance overhead when using this approach, but not because of implicit casts to ints, but rather because manipulating a bitmap is more tricky than directly manipulating array members.

A small example might help to illustrate:

Using a normal integer matrix:

```
int mat[8*8]; // assuming row major order
int is_element_set(int x, int y) { 
  return mat[y*8 + x];
}
```

With a bitmap:

```
unsigned char mat[8]; // assuming CHAR_BIT == 8
int is_element_set(int x, int y) { 
  return mat[y] & (1 << x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd rather have less space efficiency rather than take  a knock on performance, so it seems I've done it as best I can? Also since my bitfield would be approx 5000000000000000 bits, what kind of type could I store it in?

Comment: You would store it in `5e13/8` chars, or `5e13/32` ints.   Either way that's >~5 Terrabytes - So i would definitely consider space efficiency - getting that data in and out of main memory is not going to be fast.

Comment: That's A LOT of bits. In principle you would be storing it in `unsigned char mat[5000000000000000/CHAR_BIT]`, but it sounds like you might be better off looking at sparse data structures (if your data is sparse).

Comment: @Griffin Smaller space might in many cases be more efficient even if your code have to do a bit more work, since smaller data might fit in caches which are an order of magnitude faster than operating on the main memory. You'll only know by measuring for your particular case.

Comment: +1 to your answer. As you can see from the other answer, I have a lot to think about. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 4):

5e13 that's about 5.6 terabytes of storage you would need only to represent your bitfield. There's probably a better way to handle your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use some wise implementation of the bit field structs available in ANSI C.

Something like this:

```
typedef struct node_t_
{
    char bit0 : 1;
    char bit1 : 1;
    char bit2 : 1;
    char bit3 : 1;
    char bit4 : 1;
    char bit5 : 1;
    char bit6 : 1;
    char bit7 : 1;
} node_t;
```

Then, you could make some fast functions (maybe macros) to get and set elements in this matrix. I haven't ever implemented something like this, though.

Answer (score 1):

C99 `stdbool.h` allows the use of `bool`. However here your problem is that 4.9999995e13/8 would give more or less 6.2500e+12 ($10^9$ are Gbyte, $10^12$ are Tbyte), so you need more than 6 Tbytes of real + virtual memory (to be lucky). This suggests you are doing something else wrong. You need to "scale" your problem in subproblems you can handle using less memory.

Answer (score 1):

As other people have suggested, you should probably use a bitfield.

In addition though, if you're just using true/false values, and one of the values is much less common than the other, consider using an implicit coding. You can accomplish this easily with a map data structure. As you're doing work with graphs, this will save you an enormous amount of memory if your graph is at all sparse. If you combine this with the bit packing techniques above, you might even fit it all in RAM. Have to be pretty clever about the indexing though.

The other thing you could do, if you don't care about taking a performance hit during processing (i.e. if you're more worried about *storing* it than processing it), is run the structure through a compression algorithm in blocks. There's a C library for bzip2 which might save you 90% or more on something like that. Drawbacks are that this would take a (very!) long time. You might get comparable performance out of a bitwise compressor like Dynamic Markov Compression (DMC) on this, and those are much faster.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to squeeze as much out of my memory as possible.

If this were true, then you would not waste 8 bits to store 1 bit worth of data. You'd use a bitfield.

If you know anything about the sort of contents the matrix has, then you can use other optimizations. For example, if you know that the vast majority of the matrix is usually set to zero, then you can store only the x,y pairs of the elements set to one.

If not, then 4.9999995e13 will take about 6 TB of RAM!